# Install MySQL WorkBench on Centos 5.8

Tags: mysql-workbench

I tried to install MySQL WorkBench on Centos 5.8. It shows this.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/python is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libantlr3c.so is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libatkmm-1.6.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libcairomm-1.0.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libcrypto.so.10 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libctemplate.so.2 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libgdkmm-2.4.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libgio-2.0.so.0 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libgiomm-2.4.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libglibmm-2.4.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libgtkmm-2.4.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    liblua-5.1.so is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libmysqlclient.so.18 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libpangomm-1.4.so.1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libpython2.7.so.1.0 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libsigc-2.0.so.0 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libssl.so.10 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libuuid.so.1(UUID_1.0) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.4.30) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libxml2.so.2(LIBXML2_2.6.0) is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    libzip.so.2 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    pexpect is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    python-paramiko is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686
```

My command line:

```
rpm -i mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686.rpm     Any idea or suggestion? Thank you in advance
```

Comment: This answer worked for me:  https://superuser.com/questions/785814/installing-mysql-workbench-on-centos/1511574#1511574

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
yum install mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.44-1fc17.i686.rpm
```

so it can take care of the needed dependencies.